# IHandleMessages is not working in NServiceBus

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

I use nservicebus with rabbitmq.
When I Send(command) to rabbitmq I can see that message goes to my queue QUEUE_NAME@PC_Name.

I also have IHandleMessages<> for my command. However my command never handled. First question "What's wrong"?. Why handler not fired?

Also I download nservicebus sources from github and try to find place where Handler should be executed. Am I right that PipelineExecutor.Execute<> push message to queue and after that pop it?

BR, Igor

Comment: This is a bit broad so it's difficult to say what the problem might be. I would suggest checking out the RabbitMQ Samples as a first step: http://docs.particular.net/samples/rabbitmq/ After that, if you have a specific question, post it in the Particular Software Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I do not run bus.

There is an IStartableBus interface which is contain Run() method. You should call it in order to be able to get messages from RabbitMq